# Appending script to DOM issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am testing Google Hotel Pricing Tool, when I paste script directly between head tag it is working fine, appends values to DOM (screenshot is attached).
[image] But if create script programmatically it fails to create those values.Code is shown bellow:

Working example:

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var google_conversion_id = 1;
        var google_conversion_domain = "www.googletraveladservices.com/travel/clk";
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>
</head>
```

Non working example:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var google_conversion_id = 1;
    var google_conversion_domain = "www.googletraveladservices.com/travel/clk";
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js";
    document.head.appendChild(s);
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you using those variables ?

Comment: Actually script is picking up those variables and creates secondary response on page.

Comment: Can you define not working? Is the script tag created? Does it have the correct `src`? Does it load the JS and throw an exception? Does it just run and do nothing?

Comment: Script tag is created but it have different behavior than first example.It does`t append variables to DOM shown on screenshot above.

Comment: The variables get loaded/set just fine in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/Levrxjun/, you must be doing something else in your script or looking for them at the wrong time